# publishing a mobile application with Marketing content on App Store

Tags: ios, mobile

I'm developping a mobile app that is simply a presentation of a product (what it is for? how to use it? and other details). It's meant for the commercials to present the product in a more comfortable way than a simple pdf to a client.

I've read recently that the apple team doesn't allow to publish on the app store apps with only marketing content.

Do you think I would have problems when publishing the app? Do you have a clue how I can solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes you might have, apple may reject apps they consider `Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected`. You can read the full apps tore guide lines [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). But more on the subject we, as in not the Apple review board, can't answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've read the guidelines. Have to make ituseful then. I think of adding a tutorial for the users (doctors) or an educational content for the patients (ex: tooth extraction and healing...). Hope this will work.

Comment: Be aware that with a medical app Apple might request some more information about the source of the medical information in your app. Just because they want to make sure people ar informed by a correct medical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Sure, it would probably be rejected

(2) Depending on your needs -- the solution is simple, make an "[enterprise app](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)" which is sort of a private app for your company.

You can find 1000s of QA on here about enterprise apps.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I'm not sure whether the entreprise app solution will suit them, the potential users are all around the world and it would be difficult to control the devices.

Comment: Maybe if we add functionnalities such as an animated tutorial of how to use the different presentations of the product (medical) or something else that would be useful.

Comment: For me, it's difficult to see why you would not simply create "a web page" for this.  Or ideally, a "web app" -- far better than an actual app for such a use case.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

TyrAds is a [mobile app marketing agency](https://tyrads.com/) focused on delivering new, global users for our clients. Specializing in user acquisition and monetization, They provide a holistic approach to promoting your app through premium ad placements within alternative app stores. Furthermore, They are able to promote your apps on major advertising networks. TyrAds is here to help you reach the app users you need to grow your business to the next level.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).